# Automaticamente centralizar o Google Map entre dois marcadores

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tendo dificuldade ao tentar centralizar o mapa entre dois marcadores. Eu preciso fazer isso quando eu mudar o `DirectionsRenderer` de um mapa para outro. Se a rota não tem alterações que podem ser arrastadas em seguida, o mapa irá centralizar automaticamente. Mas se ocorrer alterações,o mapa irá manter o mesmo centro e zoom.

> Resumindo : O que eu quero é centralizar o mapa entre o ponto do começo e o ponto do fim da rota.

Answer (score 4):

Tem um jeito facil de fazer isso, usando  LatLngBounds

Adicione ao seu codigo

```
//create empty LatLngBounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();    

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
  bounds.extend(marker.position);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

//now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);

//(optional) restore the zoom level after the map is done scaling
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    map.setZoom(3);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});
```

Dessa forma, você pode adcionar varios pontos.

Demomostração jsFiddle aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/x5R63/